# Make textbox ignore style in css

Tags: css

I have a textbox with id="Email" in my view and I need the id to stay as it is. However, there is a #Email fields in a css file and my textbox gets the style in that fields. How can I make it to ignore that style?

Comment: You can either group it or override it by resetting the attributes. Check my answer.

Comment: Praveen Kumar has the right answer, but another pointer is that it's just not best practice to reuse ids on a single document (i.e. having two elements whose id is Email).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your css file try to write some parent element id before `#email` which is not present in case of `<input id="email">`

Answer (score 2):

Can you group the `#Email` in your CSS inside the required place? For example, may be the `#Email` should be coming inside some `.article` or something.

Instead of having CSS like:

```
#Email {background: #ccc;}
```

You can consider writing as:

```
.article #Email, p #Email {background: #ccc;}
```

Or, alternatively, you can do this way. Since you know that you won't want the `input` with `#Email` to be styled, you can write a CSS:

```
input#Email {background: none;}
```

And reset the above global styles.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not without changing the ID or overwriting the styles imposed. This is what CSS *does*. Try to avoid ambiguities like this in your stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite you property. Write like this

```
input#Email{
 color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better change ID for your text box from `Email` to Other ID

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

1. Change the CSS, it points to an ID explicitly so you'd expect it
   to do that, ID bound styles aren't my favourite anyway, consider
   making it a regular style so you can use class="email" in your
   markup or making it more specific so it isn't a blanket ID binding
2. Change the ID in the markup (you've indicated you can't
   do this)
3. Remove the class using jQuery, messy and hacky

Answer (score 0):

You could define the 'style=""' attribute (explicit style for the textbox) and overwrite the styles delivered, manually. But you cant just globaly 'deny' all styles.

```
<textbox id="email" style="...">
...
</textbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the CSS setting just ignored. You need to override it, one way or another. That is, you cannot tell the browser to do what it would do if the style setting were not present, but you can tell it display elements your way.

If you have several text input fields and one of them is affected by some CSS rule, then it is normally best to set the style of all text input fields uniformly (not necessarily the same, since at least the widths might be varied to promote usability). But since there is a CSS rule using an id selector, which has high specificity, you need to take that into account so that your rule will get applied to that element too. For example:

```
input, input#Email {
  font: 100% Calibri, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
```